# Why denormalize not return nested object?

Tags: javascript, redux, normalization, normalizr

I use `denormalize` from `normalizr` package as the following code:

```
import { normalize, schema, denormalize } from 'normalizr';

const categoriesData = [
  { id: 1, name: 'category-1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'category-2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'category-3' },
  { id: 40, name: 'category-40' },
];

const subCategoriesData = [
  { id: 1, name: 'sub-category-a', category: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'sub-category-b', category: 2 },
  { id: 3, name: 'sub-category-c', category: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: 'sub-category-d', category: 3 },
  { id: 500, name: 'sub-category-e', category: 40 },
]

const category = new schema.Entity('categories');
const categories = new schema.Array(category);

const subcategory = new schema.Entity('subCategories');
const subcategories = new schema.Array(subcategory);

const normalizedData = normalize(categoriesData, categories);
const denormalizedData = denormalize(normalizedData.result, categories, normalizedData.entities);

console.log({ normalizedData });
console.log({ denormalizedData });

const normalizedData2 = normalize(subCategoriesData, subcategories);
const denormalizedData2 = denormalize(normalizedData2.result, subcategories, normalizedData2.entities);

console.log({ normalizedData2 });
console.log({ denormalizedData2 });
```

The output of denormalizedData2 is

```
{id: 1, name: "sub-category-a", category: 1},
...
```

And I was expecting to be:

```
{id: 1, name: "sub-category-a", category: { id: 1, name: 'category-1' } },
...
```

How to use `normalizr` to achieve the goal?

Comment: Because there is no code here that brings `categoriesData` into `denormalizedData2`.

Comment: I edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but in case somebody needs an answer.
Your schema is wrong.
Instead of

> `const subcategory = new schema.Entity('subCategories');`

you should write

> `const subcategory = new schema.Entity('subCategories', { category: category });`

This means that subcategory has property `category` which is described by `category` schema.